# Can't identify SMD aluminium caps

Tags: capacitor, identification, components, surface-mount

[image]

Hello, 
I need to identify two SMD Elec. caps. But I can't find specs that would match the marking on a components. 
Top left cap is - 35 10 16f. looks like 35V 10μF 20% Kemet but not 100% sure. 
https://ru.mouser.com/datasheet/2/212/KEM_A4002_EEV-1101492.pdf 
Bottom right cap is - 47 4s. A23 looks like it Panasonic 4V.DC 47μF. 
https://ru.mouser.com/datasheet/2/315/ABA0000C1145-947633.pdf

I hope that someone can help me.

Comment: *Why* do you need to identify them?  Have you considered removing them to measure?   What does this part of the equipment do?  The small traces and presence of series resistors make it look like they may be in a *signal* filtering role... audio?

Comment: I'm trying to recreate the schematic in NI Multisim. this is an active lowpass / bandpass filter based on Mооg lаdder filter.

Comment: Why not put your guesses into the simulator and see if the resulting response makes sense?  If you're off by an order of magnitude, you'll probably know.